# How come async/await doesn't work in my code?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, async-await, undefined

How come this async/await doesn't work?

I've spent all day trying different combinations, watching videos and reading about async/await to find why this doesn't work before posting this here.

I'm trying to make a second nodejs app that will run on a different port, and my main app will call this so it scrap some data and save it to the db for cache.

What it's suppose to do:
Take a keyword and send it to a method called **scrapSearch**, this method create a complete URI link and send it to the method that actually get the webpage and returns it up to the first caller.

What is happening:
The console.log below the initial call is triggered before the results are returned.

**Console output**

```
Requesting : https://www.google.ca/?q=mykeyword

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
      at /DarkHawk/srv/NodesProjects/_scraper/node_scrapper.js:34:18
      at <anonymous>
```

**app.js**:

```
'use strict';
var koa = require('koa');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = new koa();
var Router = require('koa-router');
var router = new Router();

app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());
app.listen(3002, 'localhost');
router.get('/scraptest', async function(ctx, next) {
    var sfn = require('./scrap-functions.js');
    var scrapFunctions = new sfn();
    var html = await scrapFunctions.scrapSearch("mykeyword");
    console.log(html.substr(0, 20));

    //Normally here I'll be calling my other method to extract content
    let json_extracted = scrapFunctions.exGg('mykeywords', html);
    //Save to db
});
```

**scrap-functions.js**:

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
function Scraper() {
    this.html = ''; //I tried saving html in here but the main script seems to have issues
                        retrieving that

    this.kw = {};
    this.tr = {};
}

// Search G0000000gle
Scraper.prototype.scrapSearch = async function(keyword) {
    let url = "https://www.google.ca/?q="+keyword";
    let html = await this.urlRequest(url);
    return html;
};
// Get a url'S content
Scraper.prototype.urlRequest = async function(url) {
    console.log("Requesting : "+url);
    await request(url, await function(error, response, html) {
        if(error) console.error(error);
        return response;
    });
};
module.exports = Scraper;
```

I tried a lot of things but I finally gave up - I tried putting await/async before each methods - didn't work either.

Why that isn't working?

Edit: wrong function name based on the fact that I created 2 different projects for testing and I mixed the file while copy/pasting.

Comment: Where's your `scrapSearch` function?

Comment: Sorry, edited. It's the first function on the second file.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from `urlRequest`. Because it is an `async` function, it will still create a promise, but it will resolve with `undefined`. Therefore your `html` is `undefined` as seen in the error.

The problematic part is the `request` function which is a callback style function, but you're treating it as a promise. Using `await` on any value that is not a promise, won't do anything (technically it creates a promise that resolves directly with the value, but the resulting value remains the same). Both `await`s within the `urlRequest` are unnecessary.

```
request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if(error) console.error(error);
    // This return is for the callback function, not the outer function
    return response;
});
```

You cannot return a value from within the callback. As it's asynchronous, your function will already have finished by the time the callback is called. With the callback style you would do the work inside the callback.

But you can turn it into a promise. You have to create a new promise and return it from `urlRequest`. Inside the promise you do the asynchronous work (`request`) and either resolve with the value (the response) or reject with the error.

```
Scraper.prototype.urlRequest = function(url) {
    console.log("Requesting : "+url);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(response);
        });
    });
};
```

When an error occurred you want to return from the callback, so the rest (successful part) is not executed. I also removed the `async` keyword, because it's manually creating a promise.

If you're using Node 8, you can promisify the `request` function with the built-in [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

```
const util = require('util');
const request = require('request');
const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);

Scraper.prototype.urlRequest = function(url) {
    console.log("Requesting : " + url);
    return requestPromise(url);
};
```

Both versions will resolve with the `response` and to get the HTML you need to use `response.body`.

```
Scraper.prototype.scrapSearch = async function(keyword) {
    let url = "https://www.google.ca/?q=" + keyword;
    let response = await this.urlRequest(url);
    return response.body;
};
```

You still need to handle errors from the promise, either with `.catch()` on the promise, or using `try/catch` when you `await` it.

It is absolutely essential to understand promises when using `async`/`await`, because it's syntactic sugar on top of promises, to make it look more like synchronous code.

See also:

- [Understand promises before you start using async/await](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8)
- [Async functions - making promises friendly](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/async-functions)
- [Exploring ES6 - Promises for asynchronous programming](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html)